# Flipping an image vertically using for loops in Python

Tags: python, image, loops, for-loop, flip

Im trying to flip an image vertically, but the image saved ends up being the same one. I thought doing new_image.set_pixel(height-1)-r.... would have sent the pixel into the transposed vertical part. Can you give me some guidance as to what I have done wrong?

```
def flip_vert(filename):

img = load_image(filename)
height = img.get_height()
width = img.get_width()
new_img = Image(height, width)

for r in range(height):
    for c in range(width):
        temp = img.get_pixel(r, c)
        temp2 = new_img.get_pixel(r, c)
        new_img.set_pixel((height-1)-r,(width-1)-c,temp)

new_filename = 'flipv_test' + filename
img.save(new_filename)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your last line you need:

```
new_img.save(new_filename)
```

As it is written now you are saving `img`, which is the original version.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. Silly mistake.