# Python 3.6: rotation matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have intensity data (SEM.txt) and I want to rotate the image by 90 degrees by reassigning rows to columns. Python is giving me a "Code analysis invalid syntax" error where it says "for m:" - what am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=np.loadtxt("SEM.txt")
Intensity=np.loadtxt("SEM.txt")
Intensity[n,m]=Raw_Intensity
for m:
    for n:
        New_Intensity[m,n]=Raw_Intensity[n,m]
plt.imshow(New_Intensity)
```

Comment: and what would be the error you get? As we don't have your datas we can't help you without the error code.

Comment: Code analysis invalid syntax

Comment: "I doing wrong?" Well, the for loop syntax mostly.

Comment: Also, m and n are not defined. You could just transpose the image instead

Comment: what does this line supposed to do? ```Intensity[n,m]=Raw_Intensity
```
Also, if you just want the transpose you can do ```Intensity.T```

Comment: I have to duplicate the Intensity data and go through a "for m:" "for n:" nested loop in which I say: New Intensity of m,n is equal to Raw Intensity n,m.

Comment: @NotEinstein you **have** to use a for loop?

Comment: Yes, I was explained this method and I want to use it but don't know how.

Comment: @NotEinstein i tried to clarify in my answer

Comment: @SuperStew kinda like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825635/flipping-an-image-vertically-using-for-loops-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop syntax is incorrect. You need something like

```
for i in some_iterable:
    #do some stuff with i or whatever
```

Though i'm pretty sure you could replace those loops with a list comprehension like so

```
New_Intensity=[[x[1],x[0]] for x in Raw_Intensity]
```

assuming thats actually what you are trying to do....

*EDIT*

As per your comment above about needing to use for loops, you could do it like so

```
New_Intensity=[]
for x in Raw_Intensity:
    #we don't need to define x outside the for loop
    New_Intensity.append([x[1],x[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is transposing an array.  Use transpose directly.  See [numpy transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

```
New_Intensity = np.transpose(Intensity)
```

Here is a demo of what I am suggesting

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print(a)
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
b = np.transpose(a)
print(b)
[[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]]
```

If you want to do this manually then you can do it this way.

```
# get the size of the matrix
size = a.shape()
# create the output of the correct size
c = np.zeros((size[1],size[0]))
# iterate over the range of row values
for m in range(size[0]):
# iterate over the range of column values
 for n in range(size[1]):
  c[n,m]=a[m,n]
print(c)
[[ 1.  4.]
 [ 2.  5.]
 [ 3.  6.]]
```

The result is the same as just using `numpy.transpose` but with much more typing.